# Calculate $\int _{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ with the function $\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to calculate $\int _{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ with the function $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z}$.

I thought about using the closed path $\Gamma = \gamma _1 + \gamma _R + \gamma _2 + \gamma _{\epsilon}$, when:

$\gamma_1 (t) = t, t \in [i\epsilon, iR]$

$\gamma_R (t) = Re^{it}, t \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

$\gamma_2 (t) = t, t \in [-iR, -i\epsilon]$

$\gamma_{\epsilon} (t) = \epsilon e^{it}, t \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

I use the fact that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is an even function and has an anti derivative, so the integral on a closed path is zero.

I managed to show that $\int_{\gamma _{\epsilon}} f = -i\pi$ when $\epsilon \to 0$.

However I am struggling to show that $\int_{\gamma _R} f = 0$ when $R \to \infty$

Help would be appreciated

Comment: $f$ is not an even function. Also, I don't understand your parametrization. For example, $\gamma_2$ is completely disconnected from the other three (which I don't understand either).

Comment: I forgot the $i$

Comment: In fact the integral around $\gamma_R$ will not tend to zero as $R\to\infty$. Why are taking a huge semi-circle? Take a small one.

Comment: What do you mean with a small semi-circle? could you write the path?

Comment: Your path is closed and the function you want to integrate is holomorphic in a neighborhood of it. So, the integral is zero.

Comment: See [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-handout22.pdf).

Comment: I don't think I have seen Jordan's Lemma which is used there. Is there maybe a straight way to show that $\int_{\gamma _R} f \to 0$? maybe using $| \int_{} f| \le \int |f|$

Comment: There is little hope that there exists a simpler way than that used in the proof of [Jordan's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).